# Can I install a beta/alpha/development version using Wubi?

Tags: wubi, beta

How do you install the next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1) using Wubi?
When clicking the download button for the latest beta, will Wubi
show up as an option?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course, not only you can, but Ubuntu is always short on Wubi testers, you are encouraged to try it.

You will find the wubi installer inside the testing iso of development Ubuntu versions.

For 12.04, you need to download an iso from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/). You will find wubi.exe inside it.

Comment: I'm posting this from a freshly installed Wubi-based Kubuntu 12.04 Beta 2, running LXDE Wubi came a long way, I haven't encountered a crash yet in 2-days. Way back 10.04, the Wubi version there tend to crash on me within an hour (usually during boot period).